# How to append to created file on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have problem with appending to file which was created by me. I don't have such problem with file which was upload manually to HDFS. What is a difference between file upload and created?

To append and create i use code below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
public class Test {
    public static final String hdfs = "hdfs://192.168.15.62:8020";
    public static final String hpath = "/user/horton/wko/test.log";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfs);
            conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hdfs");
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            Path filenamePath = new Path(hpath);
            //FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(filenamePath);
            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(filenamePath);
            out.writeUTF("TEST\n");
            out.close();
        }
}
```

I got such exception in case append:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on   the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[192.168.15.62:50010], original=[192.168.15.62:50010]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
```

Comment: Do you have `dfs.support.append` set to `true` in hdfs-site.xml ? Also, how many datanodes do you have and what is the replication factor?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that fixed adding `conf.set("dfs.replication", "1")`.

In my case I had only one node in the cluster, and even though `dfs.replication` was set to `1` in `hdfs-site.xml`, it still was using the default value of `3`.

Note that Hadoop will try to replicate the blocks of the file as soon as they get written in the first node, and since the default value for replication is `3`, it will fail to access other nodes if you only have one node cluster.